# Non-full screen Activity in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'd like to have a non-fullscreen Activity only taking about one third of full screen on Android 3+ (Honeycomb), so that other part would be transparent and other apps would show. So my app would actually float above other open apps.

Is it possible to have an Activity that only takes 1/3 of the full screen?

If possible, is this against Honeycomb UI guidelines?

Comment: It certainly worked on 1.x/2.x -- see `Theme.Dialog`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll definitelly give this a try.

Comment: It works, width/height can be arbitrarily set, but window is always centered in the middle of the screen. Any idea how to move it? Tried `layout_x` but to no success.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't played with it much.

Comment: Update: if activity is created with `Theme.Dialog`, then it is centered, the area around it is dimmed and there is no access to underlying activities or desktop (i.e. dialog is modal). So there is no practical way of having a non-fullscreen window in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question to let you know what I discovered:

If activity is created with `Theme.Dialog`, then it is centered and there is no way to move it. Also area around it is dimmed and there is no access to underlying activities or desktop (i.e. activity window is modal). So there is no practical way of having a non-fullscreen window in Android that would behave as a floating window in a similar way as windows on desktop OSes do.

Comment: "Also area around it is dimmed and there is no access to underlying activities or desktop" -- oh, sure. You did not specify that requirement in your question. You asked for other activities to *show*, not be responsive to input. Sorry for the wild goose chase.

Comment: But how is made the calculator application? In my Galaxy Tab 10.1 it's like a floating activity